# DevDays 2009 Reviews - Los Angeles

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2009

Some LA reviews are already popping up on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/#search?q=%23devdays), but there's no place on Meta for them yet, so here goes...

If you were there, can you write a review of the [Los Angeles leg](http://stackoverflow.carsonified.com/events/losangeles/) of Stack Overflow DevDays? Links to reviews in blogs, etc, are also welcome.

#### DevDays reviews

- [Boston](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24994/devdays-reviews-boston) (Oct 7th)
- [Austin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/reviews-of-devdays-austin) (Oct 14th)
- **Los Angeles** (Oct 16th)
- [San Francisco](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26536/devdays-reviews-san-francisco) (Oct 19th)
- [Seattle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26873/devdays-reviews-seattle) (Oct 21st)
- [Toronto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27151/devdays-reviews-toronto) (Oct 23rd)
- [Washington DC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27367/devdays-reviews-washington-dc) (Oct 26th)
- [London](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/devdays-reviews-london) (Oct 28th)
- [Cambridge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27959/devdays-reviews-cambridge) (Oct 30th)
- [Amsterdam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28160/devdays-reviews-amsterdam) (Nov 2nd)

Intentionally **not** a wiki (as per comments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24994/devdays-reviews-boston)).

Comment: Right, people don't seem very eager about posting their stuff here (despite asking those who tweeted about it) :-/ So I'll go ahead and share the two reviews that I'm aware of, in CW answers.

Answer (score 1):

Review by [Robert Navarro](http://www.crshman.com/) ([twitter.com/crshman](http://twitter.com/crshman)):

**[Dev Days LA 2009](http://www.crshman.com/?p=257)**

Answer (score 1):

Review by [Rick Fleischer](http://iamgoat.com/) ([twitter.com/iamgoat](http://twitter.com/iamgoat)):

**[StackOverflow DevDays Conference](http://iamgoat.com/post.cfm/stackoverflow-devdays-conference)**

Quoting the sum-up:

> [...]
>
> In the end, would I go next year? 
>   Yes! The price alone makes it a
>   no-brainer.  However, if it's the same
>   talks it will get boring fast.  The
>   presentations were all introductory
>   and pretty easy to grasp.  More
>   intermediate talks would be cool. 
>   Technology is always advancing so I
>   imagine it won't be hard to find new
>   topics.  Couch DB or principle talks
>   of software development / project
>   management would be great. I hope some
>   people post pics. I wanted to do a Qik
>   video stream, but wasn't sure if it
>   would be allowed.