# DevDays Presentation Resources - Washington DC

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2009, devdays-dc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DevDays reviews - Washington DC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27367/devdays-reviews-washington-dc)

Are there any of the DC DevDays presentations, sideshows, audio..etc available?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27367/devdays-reviews-washington-dc