# DevDays DC Soundtrack -- Does anyone have a list of all the songs played?

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2009, devdays-dc

I only recognized/found these:

- Drive In, Drive Out (Dave Matthews Band)
- Cinnamon (The Long Winters)
- Crazy in Love by (Beyonce and Jay-Z)
- A Little Less Conversation (Elvis Presley vs. JXL)
- Throwing Stones (Grateful Dead)
- Tangled Up in Blue (Indigo Girls?)

Comment: the DMB song was badass.

Comment: DMB is one of my favorite bands.

Answer (score 1):

Joel's Entrance Music was Crazy in Love by Beyonce and Jay-Z

I think everybody else used A Little Less Conversation - Elvis Presley vs. JXL

Answer (score 1):

There was quite a few Vampire Weekend tunes before everything started.

During the lunch break, when the music took a turn, I remember the Grateful Dead's "throwing stones" and a cover (Indigo Girls?) of Dylan's "Tangled Up in Blue".

Answer (score 0):

Guess I'm a geezer, since I didn't recognize most of the stuff played, and some of what I had heard before I couldn't identify.  However, I do recall that they played something by Peter Gabriel during lunch, but I don't remember which tune.