# DevDays London - Can I get hold of the presentation material?

Tags: discussion, questions, devdays-london

I didn't take much notes as I assumed there would be a URL I could go to.

I have emailed Carsonified with no response.

Answer (score 6):

Each speaker will probably have their own notes somewhere. I don't have any published yet, but I was considering writing a blog post basically consisting of my "script" with slides, and a link to the video when it's published.

We might as well use this question to aggregate all that information.

From my talk:

- [Blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) with slides
- [High quality video](http://vimeo.com/7516539) (in terms of the picture; the content is as bad as it ever was!)
- [Blog post from Carsonified](http://carsonified.com/blog/dev/jon-skeet-at-stack-overflow-dev-days-london/)

Comment: Are you planning to market that pony puppet glove (sorry can't remember it's name) thing as well ? LOL

Comment: @Ferds: Tony the Pony

Comment: Tony will next be appearing in the 9th Tilehurst Guides Pantomime. After that I expect I'll take him to another talk or two :)

Comment: Is there a time frame for the video? I won't hold you to it, but it would be nice to know if it's coming in a day, a week, a month, etc. Thanks :-)

Comment: I've no idea, I'm afraid - I'm not working on it myself. I'll try to write up the slides and notes as a blog post in the meantime though...

Comment: Who is? If it's not too much of an imposition, would you mind just posting whatever you have, in whatever format you have, for the time being?

Comment: Carsonified is doing it... and I'm afraid I'm not going to post what I've got, as it's 2GB, would take forever to upload, and wreck the bandwidth of wherever I uploaded it to :) I'll see if I can get an estimate though...

Comment: They're having some problems with it at Carsonified. I'm going to do what I can with my copy tonight, at a relatively low quality setting (so that it doesn't completely kill my net connection)... that means we should have something up soon, and Carsonified can put a better one up later.

Comment: I suggest setting up a torrent - I can kick in some bandwidth and have my web host seed the file.

Comment: @Kyle: I'm going to try to get it down to a reasonable amount to start with, then upload it to Vimeo. It's really the initial upload over my ADSL connection which is going to be the pain :)

Answer (score 4):

The slides and code from the Cambridge live demo for my jQuery talk is available here: http://remysharp.com/talks/#2009_stackoverflow (note that the slides also include links to jsbin.com to view and play with the demos live)

Comment: Thanks.  It was a very good presentation and has 'tickled my tastebuds' to get into JQuery.  Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

I just got this email from fogcreek.  Not too sure if it's already up here.

### Reviews:

[DevDays 2009 Reviews - London](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/devdays-reviews-london)

### Python: Michael Sparks

http://www.python.org/

http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

### Android: Reto Meir

http://code.google.com/android

### jQuery: Remy Sharp

http://jquery.com/

### FogBugz 7: Joel Spolsky

http://fogbugz.com/

### The kiln beta is at:

http://fogcreek.com/kiln

### Business Of Software Conference 2009

http://businessofsoftware.org/

November 9-11 <-- That's SOON!

### Stack Exchange Beta

http://stackexchange.com

### Stack Overflow Careers

http://careers.stackoverflow.com

### Qt: Pekka Kosonen

http://qt.nokia.com/

http://getjar.com/

### "Make Better Software": The Training Series

http://training.fogcreek.com

### Donors Choose

http://donorschoose.org/stackoverflow

Stack Overflow has a page at Donors Choose which allows you to donate to a bunch of our favorite causes. Donors Choose is an awesome organization. Please consider helping! (Currently there are only 9 donations.)

### iPhone: Phil Nash

http://www.levelofindirection.com/journal/2009/10/29/stackoverflow-devdays-london.html

### Jon Skeet

http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/

http://is.gd/4LQTV

### Paul Biggar

[https://www.cs.tcd.ie/~pbiggar/#so-2009](https://www.cs.tcd.ie/%7Epbiggar/#so-2009)

### Yahoo: Christian Heilmann

http://developer.yahoo.com/

http://is.gd/4IibE

### Some photos:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/pepez/sets/72157622685399650/

http://picasaweb.google.com/brunorothgiesser/DevDaysLondon